# I have 4 test cases added in conf.js file inside spec[] and I have to run 2 test cases from them without removing any test case from conf.js file

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

there are 4 test cases in my application and I will have to run 2 tests from them, without removing any file from `conf.js`

Here is the `conf.js`:

```
framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
//  specs: ['spec.js']

specs: ['spec1.js', 'spec2.js', 'spec3.js', 'spec4.js']
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, you can then easily switch between running one or two tests. The command will run the `spec2` and the `spec3`:

`--specs` option expects a comma-separated list of files to test `--specs spec2.js,spec3.js`.

For instance:

```
protractor conf.js --specs spec2.js,spec3.js
```

Comment: Yes that will work, but if there are 500 test-cases and I need to run 300, in that case we can't run through command line as it take much more time .

Comment: For this case, you should split your tests by `suites`. Need to add suites in the `conf.js` file and then you can run with the `--suites` option. For instance `protractor conf.js --suite smoke`. Read more https://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects#configuring-test-suites.

Comment: Hey @Chetan. What do you think about `suites`? Did it help you?

Comment: hey @Yevhen   I wrote  xdescribe and xit  for those testcases which I don't want to run. and it's work fine even I tried your solution too, it also working fine.